# Yearly disaster recovery Exercise in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In order to address business requirement of yearly disaster recovery Exercise, any good suggestion for Cassandra setup in (3node-dc1)(3node-dc2) configuration?

The exercise is to **simulate DR activation**, but production workload still use DC1 to serve.

In the pace time, DC1 is the main DC to handle the workload, DC2 running spark analytics on Cassandra node only, no other workload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the cloud (like AWS, Google Cloud Services) or are you running the database in dedicated hardware? 
You mentioned 2 datacenters, are they part of the same cluster?

More than a special configuration to comply with your annual DR exercise, it would be better if you are prepared for any contingency:

- have periodic and automated backups,
- on our case, we take full daily snapshots, stored on S3, with expiration policies (only the latest 7 daily backups, last 4 weekly backups, last 3 monthly backups)
- verify that the backups are able to be restored, and this is usually done on temporary AWS EC2 instances
- tests or research in the restored instances do not communicate with the productive cluster, once that the test is done, the instances are terminated

For more detail, a coworker gave a talk for the [Cassandra Summit 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyI4cmRMf5w) with more detail about our process.

Comment: Thanks, 2 data centers are both on-premise with dedicated hardware. And they forum a big cluster. (Dc2 used for apache spark job in pace time). I like your idea about testing backup restore using separate nodes.